# Namespace resolution for graphql schema

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

If I want to create 2 different User types based on context, how can I achieve it in graphql without naming them differently? Does graphql support namespaces or that concept in any form that we can achieve the same behavior? Please advise.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with both `graphql-java` and `express-graphql`? This seems like it's a generic GraphQL question anyway. If you want to limit it to a specific implementation you can but presumably you're not running both a Java and a Node.js server.

Answer (score 6):

From the [spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Schema):

> All types within a GraphQL schema must have unique names. No two provided types may have the same name. No provided type may have a name which conflicts with any built in types (including Scalar and Introspection types).

There is no concept of "namespaces" in GraphQL. A schema has operations, types, fields, arguments and directives -- that's it.

There's nothing wrong with having a single domain model (i.e. `User`) that maps to multiple types in your schema (i.e. `Viewer` and `Friend`).

Answer (score 3):

Currently the proposal ticket status is **`open`**, track it **[here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/163)**